# Converting EmguCV/OpenCV to Windows Phone Runtime

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, emgucv

I'd like to know whether there are any image processing libraries available for Windows Phone 7 apps.

EmguCV (.net wrapper for OpenCV) has all the features I want but I'm unable to use it on Windows Phone development as it encounters a runtime conflict. Is there any way I can convert this to a Silverlight/Windows Phone runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588942/windows-phone-6-vs-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute unmanaged code in a 3rd party app. Emgucv is just a wrapper and uses the unmanaged OpenCV. There's no real managed port out there. You'll have to port it yourself from the C codebase.

Comment: and that isn't a realistic goal, of course, unless you need something very specific

Comment: @ReneSchulte Judging from your blog comments, you're likely working on something like that.  How's that working out?

Comment: See http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/FaceLight--Silverlight-4-Real-Time-Face-Detection